# linq vb.net change value

Tags: vb.net, linq, list

How to change 1 property of 1 (or more) specified item in a list of object

```
Class Item
    Private _Id As Integer
    Private _Value As Boolean 'can be string, int , .....

    Public Property Id() As Integer
        Get
            Return _Id
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _Id = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property Value() As Boolean
        Get
            Return _Value
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            _Value = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New(ByVal id As Integer, ByVal value As Boolean)
        Me.Id = id
        Me.Value = value
    End Sub       
End Class
```

...

```
Dim lst As New List(Of Item)
lst.Add(New Item(1, True))
lst.Add(New Item(2, True))
lst.Add(New Item(3, True))

lst = from l in lst select l ' and change the value of the element 2 to FALSE
```

result

List before

```
Item
[_Id = 1] 
[_Value = True] 

Item
[_Id = 2] 
[_Value = True] 

Item
[_Id = 3] 
[_Value = True]
```

List after

```
Item
[_Id = 1] 
[_Value = True] 

Item
[_Id = 2] 
[_Value = False] 

Item
[_Id = 3] 
[_Value = True]
```

Answer (score 1):

Linq is for *querying* not *updating*.  To update use traditional loops and/or indexers:

```
l(2).Value = false
```

Or if you want to use Linq to determine *which* object(s) to change just loop over the results of a query:

```
Dim query = From l In lst Where l.Id = 2 Select l
For Each l In query
   l.Value = false
Next l
```

or, since you only expect one item:

```
Dim query = From l In lst Where l.Id = 2 Select l
query.Single().Value = False
```

Your original list will then have an updated item since the list and the query hold *references* to the items.

If, however, you want a list of NEW `Item`s with slightly different values, then that's possible:

```
Dim query = From l In lst _
            Select New Item With { _ 
               ID = l.ID, _
               Value = IIf(l.ID = 2, False, l.Value) _
            }
```

but be aware that this create NEW `Item`s, it does NOT modify the existing `Item`s stored in the original list.

Comment: the problem its I want to keep the list, so your second code keep only the selected items.

Comment: and l(2).value its the position, but the position can change, I need to use the id value.

Comment: if linq cant do that, I will use the old loop and if

Comment: @forX - not sure I understand - you already _have_ a list.  My second example was just to select the items to update (modified to address your second comment).  You can select _new_ items with Linq but you can't modify _existing_ items.  If you want a _new_ list with slightly different items then that's possible.

Comment: yeah, I want the same list, with 1 property different.

Comment: @forX OK I see your problem - you're _overwriting_ the original list.  I'll update.